# Can you use OneDrive Graph API to Download files in bulk?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am a Java application developer that wants to use Microsoft Graph API to download onedrive files.

Is there a OneDrive Graph API method that can download multiple files in bulk? Or are you forced to use a file-by-file download approach?

I've googled for a while now to see if I can find some answer to this. I did find: https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/9255150-multiple-file-download-onedrive-for-business
Which states that you can actually use OneDrive web UI to download files in bulk.

But does it exist for API?